# swiper js multiple slides per view

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, swiper.js

Trying to make swiper with 3 slides per view, but all slides shows in same time. Can't get what is the problem. Please check my sandbox : https://codesandbox.io/s/condescending-maxwell-vlxev

```
function swiperTours() {
  var swiper = new Swiper("#tours.swiper-container", {
    slidesPerView: 3,
    navigation: {
      nextEl: ".swiper-button-next.tours-btn_next",
      prevEl: ".swiper-button-prev.tours-btn_prev"
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing swiper.min.css file. And you should remove your custom styles on swiper blocks.
Some dirty code here as example: https://codesandbox.io/s/charming-solomon-y1i8q